# How to create a customized Linear Operator to solve Ax = b?

Tags: python, linear-algebra

I want to create a linear operator in python to solve Ax = b where A is a large-scale dense Matrix of float64. Since matrix A cause both performance and memory problems I thought about creating a customized operator as follows:

```
from numpy import ones
from numpy.linalg import inv
import scipy.sparse.linalg
from sklearn.datasets import make_spd_matrix

n = 100


def solver(A, b):
    return inv(A).dot(b)


M = make_spd_matrix(n, random_state=11)
print(M.shape)
solverFunc = scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator((n, n), matvec=solver)

solverFunc.matvec(M, ones((n, 1)))
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anoir\Desktop\CG_accelerator\inversion\main.py", line 15, in <module>
    solverFunc = LinearOperator((n, n), matvec=solver)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\inversion\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\interface.py", line 521, in __init__
    self._init_dtype()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\inversion\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\interface.py", line 178, in _init_dtype
    self.dtype = np.asarray(self.matvec(v)).dtype
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\inversion\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\interface.py", line 232, in matvec
    y = self._matvec(x)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\inversion\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\interface.py", line 530, in _matvec
    return self.__matvec_impl(x)
TypeError: solver() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

What seems to be the problem here? I followed the documentation but there is nothing about custom LinearOperator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear operator only takes one parameter. You can get around this by using a closure as shown below:

```
from numpy.linalg import inv
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse.linalg
from scipy.sparse import random
import timeit

n = 100

def solver_closure(A):
    # This is the outer enclosing function
    def solver(b):
        return inv(A).dot(b)
    return solver  # returns the nested function

M = np.random.rand(n, n)
b = range(n)
print(M.shape)

solverFunc = scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator((n, n), matvec=solver_closure(M))

def test100():
    x = solverFunc.matvec(b)
    print(np.matmul(M,x))

print(timeit.timeit("test100()", setup="from __main__ import test100",number=10))
```